# IE-11, Posted data request's response is not displayed

Tags: azure, internet-explorer, post, internet-explorer-11

I'm posting Zip file of size >400MB in one of web page at Cloudapp.net (Azure hosted site) using IE as well as Chrome. After the request page redirect to result page. It takes around 15 minutes to process Zip file including upload. In Chrome it works fine but in Internet Explorer (11) the request is pending even after the Zip has been processed successfully.

[image]

What could be possible changes I can make it to wait or show results?

Following is exported NetworkData for request if could be helpful:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <log>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <creator>
            <name>Internet Explorer Network Inspector</name>
            <version>11.0.9600.17840</version>
        </creator>
        <browser>
            <name>Internet Explorer</name>
            <version>11.0.9600.17840</version>
        </browser>
        <pages>
            <page>
                <startedDateTime>2017-03-23T05:01:43.105+05:30</startedDateTime>
                <id>0</id>
                <title/>
                <pageTimings>
                    <onContentLoad>-1</onContentLoad>
                    <onLoad>-1</onLoad>
                </pageTimings>
            </page>
        </pages>
        <entries>
            <entry>
                <pageref>0</pageref>
                <startedDateTime>2017-03-23T05:01:43.105+05:30</startedDateTime>
                <time>291860</time>
                <request>
                    <method/>
                    <url>http://MY_CLOUD_APP_SITE.cloudapp.net/Admin/Import</url>
                    <httpVersion/>
                    <cookies/>
                    <headers/>
                    <queryString/>
                    <headersSize>0</headersSize>
                    <bodySize>0</bodySize>
                </request>
                <response>
                    <cookies/>
                    <headers/>
                    <content>
                        <size>0</size>
                        <mimeType/>
                    </content>
                    <redirectionURL/>
                    <headersSize>0</headersSize>
                    <bodySize>0</bodySize>
                </response>
                <cache/>
                <timings>
                    <send>0</send>
                    <wait>-1</wait>
                    <receive>-1</receive>
                </timings>
            </entry>
        </entries>
    </log>
```